# How to open a second Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive

*What I want to do*:
I have a hard drive installed with 12.04 64-bit. This however is quite a small solid state drive and I would like to move games, large files etc. to another hard drive that is much bigger, but keep Ubuntu on my small hard drive.

*The problem*:
I can't find the HDD even though it shows up in "**Storage Devices**" (sorry not very good at explaining it).

I also looked in `/media` (as this is where CD and other external devices can be opened from) also looked in `/dev`. Am I looking in the correct place?

I think I'm correct in saying I'm looking for `F:/` (then this should be my large hard drive) but I can't find it. It also shows up in the BIOS as "being there".

Sorry I'm having one of those days where words just don't want to come together.

Comment: There are no drive letters in Linux. Run gparted and check for the drive there.

Comment: Can you post he output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Is the other hard drive an external drive that is sometimes connected, or an internal drive on your machine.  Has the second drive been formatted before, or did it have a different operating system on before?

Answer (score 3):

Did you look for the Harddrive with 'Disk Utility'? Please look there, select the partition and click on 'Mount Partiton'. Then should pop up a new window. If not, look at '/media' :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the program < pysdm >. It's in the repository. This program allows you to control any hard drive which is on your machine. It will allow both (if you have two) drives to mount when your computer is booted and it will allow you to freely (and seamlessly) transfer files/folders back and forth.

I have an Asus EeePC 1000/Linux (which originally came with a modified-Xandros OS but on which I now use Xubuntu). This computer has two SSDs. One, the "main" one, on which the operating system is installed, is 8 GB; the other, which I use for storage, etc., is 32 GB.

Using pysdm has solved the problem of having two hard drives and using them both together.

Give it a try. You'll have to study it a bit to learn how to use it but, once learned, it is easy. I suggest that you have your second drive start in /boot; that how I have mine configured.

Good luck.